# How do you PIVOT on a Bit datatype in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is probably a very simple question.  All I want to really do is to make the column into a row whose data type is a bit.

SUM, MIN, MAX doesn't work on bits.  COUNT works but I really don't want to count. I just want to move all the stuff from columns into rows like if I took a pair of scissors, cut the information and moved it -90 degrees.

Comment: I guess are we here to make points or help others?  What can you turn those points into ?

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this is to cast the bit data type to a data type that is accepted in aggregate functions.  For example,

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT))
```

casts the BitColumn value to a tinyint datatype.  The statement returns 1 if BitColumn contains at least one value of 1; otherwise, it returns 0 (unless all values are null).

Assuming the following:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10), BitColumn BIT);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, 'Name 1', 1);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, 'Name 2', 0);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, 'Name 3', 1);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, 'Name 1', 1);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, 'Name 2', 1);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, 'Name 3', 1);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, 'Name 1', 0);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, 'Name 2', 0);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, 'Name 3', 0);
```

You can pivot this data using the following query

```
SELECT ID,
    CAST(MAX(CASE Name WHEN 'Name 1' THEN CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT) ELSE NULL END) AS BIT) AS [Name 1],
    CAST(MAX(CASE Name WHEN 'Name 2' THEN CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT) ELSE NULL END) AS BIT) AS [Name 2],
    CAST(MAX(CASE Name WHEN 'Name 3' THEN CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT) ELSE NULL END) AS BIT) AS [Name 3]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

In this case, the max BitColumn value is converted back from tinyint to bit.  This is not required.

The results are

```
ID  Name 1  Name 2  Name 3
--------------------------
1   1       0       1
2   1       1       1
3   0       0       0
```

An alternative query, for SQL Server 2005 and later, uses the PIVOT operator

```
SELECT ID, [Name 1], [Name 2], [Name 3]
FROM
    (
    SELECT ID, Name, CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT) AS BitColumn
    FROM MyTable
    ) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(BitColumn) FOR Name in ([Name 1], [Name 2], [Name 3])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: this solutuon works. But won't return bit values when you exec query. 
its possible to cast  pivot columns but when its a dynamic pivot its a bit hard.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [1], [2], [3]
FROM
    (
    SELECT ID, CAST(BitColumn AS TINYINT) AS INTColumn
    FROM MyTable
    ) as SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(INTColumn) FOR ID in ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: this solutuon works. But won't return bit values when you exec query.